# How to assign a string to a variable in javascript when the string has a single quote in it

Tags: javascript, string

In my program there is a variable name 'quotes' which takes an input string from an API call.
**Program doesn't work when the string has a single quote in it.**

```
<script>
    var quotes = "Empty"
        if(user.quotes)
           quotes = user.quotes;    // get the string to 'quotes' variable
</script>
```

can any one please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What does or doesn't it do then, where/how/what exactly are you doing with the data?

Comment: Problem is somewhere else, probably in the place where the "quotes" variable is consumed.

Comment: can't I just scan the string and add "\" before the single quote, before assigning it to the variable.

Comment: How is this Facebook related?

Comment: @ Jack, sorry for the mistake. This problem occurred in my facebook application, but this question is not facebook related :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace single quote (escape it like PHP):

```
<script>
    var quotes = "Empty"
        if(user.quotes)
           quotes = user.quotes.replace(/'/g,"\\\'");    // get the string to 'quotes' variable
</script>
```

Then wherever You use Your quotes, replace the "\'" back to "'".